# How to calculate the percentage in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am just trying to understand how XSLT works and writing the small code, that output the percentage of available products in the receipts.

So I have the next XML-file:

```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>     <pc:recipes
>       xmlns:pc="some-url-for-pc" 
>       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
>       <pc:recipe amount="5"></pc:ingredient>
>       <pc:recipe amount="6"></pc:ingredient>
>       <pc:recipe amount="2"></pc:ingredient>
>       <pc:recipe amount="4"></pc:ingredient> 
        </pc:recipes>
```

So what I want to calculate to divide the recipes into two classes: The first class is the recipe with too many for me ingredients (for example the recipe with 4 ingredients should be in the first class. My average value is for example 3, so the recipe with the amount of 2 should be in the second class with too few ingredients.  In the end, I want also to calculate the percentage of the recipes with too many and too few recipes, for example:

```
<result> 
   <too_much_percentage>75</too_much_percentage>
   <too_few_percentage>25</too_few_percentage>
</result>
```

I would be very grateful if someone help me with this task because I am just learning XSLT and it looks a little bit difficult for me.

Comment: `</pc:ingredient>` does NOT close `<pc:recipe`!!!

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

Well, given a **well-formed** input such as:

**XML**

```
<pc:recipes xmlns:pc="some-url-for-pc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <pc:recipe amount="5"></pc:recipe>
    <pc:recipe amount="6"></pc:recipe>
    <pc:recipe amount="2"></pc:recipe>
    <pc:recipe amount="4"></pc:recipe> 
</pc:recipes>
```

you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:pc="some-url-for-pc" 
exclude-result-prefixes="pc">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/pc:recipes">
    <xsl:variable name="count-all" select="count(pc:recipe)" />
    <xsl:variable name="count-high" select="count(pc:recipe[@amount > 3])" />
    <xsl:variable name="count-low" select="count(pc:recipe[@amount &lt; 3])" />
    <result>
        <too_much_percentage>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($count-high div $count-all, '#%')" />
        </too_much_percentage>
        <too_few_percentage>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($count-low div $count-all, '#%')" />
        </too_few_percentage>
    </result>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <too_much_percentage>75%</too_much_percentage>
  <too_few_percentage>25%</too_few_percentage>
</result>
```