# How can I sort the attribute in two classes with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to sort the amount attribute in two classes from this XML example, so the amount attribute bigger than 100000 is in the first class (high) and the other attributes land in the second class. Also, these two classes should be saved as two different variables, so I can further calculate with them. I tried already with the count function, but the output is always incorrect:

```
<xsl:variable name="low" select="count(pc:number[pc:description/@amount &lt; 100000])" />
```

XML-file:

```
<result>
   <high>
    <numbers>
    <number>
       <description amount="100200"/>
    </number>
    <number>
       <description amount="200020200"/>
    </number>
    <number>
       <description amount="202020"/>
    </numbers>
```

Comment: Start with minimal but well-formed and complete samples, then show us the exact result you want and the exact incorrect output you get.

Comment: Isn't this the same question as your previous one https://stackoverflow.com/q/73164070/3016153?

Comment: Please take the time to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes, but my output is always incorrect, that's why I am trying to find out what am I doing wrong

Comment: We cannot tell what you're doing wrong, because we don't see what you're doing. Please provide a way to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to select the items in each group independently:

```
<xsl:variable name="low" select="//number[number(description/@amount) lt 10000]"/>
<xsl:variable name="high" select="//number[number(description/@amount) ge 10000]"/>
```

(You didn't specify an XSLT version, so I've used the `lt` and `ge' operators from 2.0, but the` <`and`>=` operators work equally well.)

Another approach (in 2.0+) is grouping on a boolean grouping key:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//number"
  group-by="boolean(description/@amount lt 10000)">...
```

(The call on the `boolean()` function is there only to alert the reader to the fact that we're using a boolean grouping key, which is a little unusual.)